# MongoDB compare arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with thousands of users. Each user document has a few properties like name, age range, and favourites.

I can easily help users find other users that are the within the same age range but I also want to somehow allow them to choose a matching percentage OR number  of the favourites they have in common with other users.

Eg.

```
User 1
Name: x
Age Range: 19-25
Favourites: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]

User 2
Name: y
Age Range: 19-25
Favourites: ["Orange", "Red", "Pink"]

User 3
Name: z
Age Range: 19-25
Favourites: ["Orange", "Red", "Blue"]
```

Here, if user 1 searched for users with a 33% match OR at least one common match, they would get only user 2. If they searched for a 66% OR at least two common matches, they would get user 3.

I've done the easy part and matched by age range and tried to work with mongoDB `$all` and `$in` but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [please check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37459177/5919473) as it looks a bit similar - if you play with redact you could have only matches and get %

Comment: How is the percentage defined? Is range a two elements array or a string?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to find objects having some common attributes, I'll take a different approach. I'll create full text index on attribute. In your particular case it's `Favorites`.

Full text index is much faster when search for text. It also gives you a [text score](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/#text-score) showing how much a given term is matching in collection.

In your particular case, I'll be measuring `text score` to see if other documents are falling with in my criteria.

You'll need to create `full text` index first.

```
db.collection.createIndex({"Favourites":"text"})
```

After creation of full text index, assuming you are trying to find all documents with at least `66%` match. It means if we have three text terms, we want all documents matching at least two out of 3 terms.

```
var match = 2;
var terms = "Red Green Blue";

db.collection.aggregate([
 { $match: { $text: { $search: terms } } },
 { $project: {User:1, _id:0, Name:1, "Age Range":1, Favourites:1, score: {$meta: "textScore"}}},
 { $sort: { score: 1 }},
 { $match: { score: { $gte: match } } }
])
```

In example above, we want to find all documents with at least two matching terms. Code snippet above will return:

```
{ 
    "User" : 3.0, 
    "Name" : "z", 
    "Age Range" : "19-25", 
    "Favourites" : [
        "Orange", 
        "Red", 
        "Blue"
    ], 
    "score" : 2.2
}
{ 
    "User" : 1.0, 
    "Name" : "x", 
    "Age Range" : "19-25", 
    "Favourites" : [
        "Red", 
        "Green", 
        "Blue"
    ], 
    "score" : 3.3000000000000003
}
```

We got back two documents matching at least two terms.

**Update:**

OP mentioned that terms can contain multi-word phrase. MongoDB full text allows to search for phrases and requires to wrap phrases around with string quotes.

e.g. `var terms = "Red \"Light Blue\"";`

Using above code snippet and provided that document contains `Light Blue` phrase in Favourites, will return matching document.

However there is a catch. MongoDB always perform `logical and` operation on phrases with rest of terms if any. In example above, code will search a document which contains phrase `Light Blue` and term `Red`

Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases

Comment: Thanks! This is a neat approach, and seems like it'll be much quicker to run. Question though, how would I handle two worded colours such as "Light Blue" or "Dark Green". Right now I'm storing all the colours as an array so it's easy to display as well, what's best practice for displaying these once they're saved as text? On the UI side, it's a multi select.

Comment: You'll need to escape it with string quotes. e.g. `"Light Blue"`. It will search entire phrase. Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases

Comment: I like this idea, working on implementing it now. I've attempted to just turn my multi select array into a string by joining the individual colours by a blank space. This will give me a property like: `Favourites: "Red Blue Light Blue"`. What's the proper approach to escape them so they're like phrases before saving the field?

Comment: I'll not recommend saving escaped fields. However, you should be doing this in your application, before passing to MongoDB query. Please see my update above.

Comment: If you don't recommend doing that then what would you recommend doing? With regards to a colour with multiple words.

Comment: Well I'm saying don't update your documents, instead escape your strings before feeding to query. .e.g. 'var terms = "Red \"Light Blue\"";`.

Answer (score 0):

[This will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153179/match-at-least-n-elements-of-an-array-to-a-list-of-conditions)
Do you expect the result as this ? 
For example:  Searched for "favourites" at least two common matches,['orange','red', 'pink'].Hence "User3" is the expectation.Query as below:

```
db.test.aggregate([ 
{"$match": 
{ 
    favourites: {"$in" : ['orange','red', 'pink']}
 } 
},
 { "$unwind": "$favourites" },
{ "$match": { favourites: { "$in":  ['orange','red', 'pink'] } }},

{"$group" :
{
    "_id": {
        "_id": {"id":"$_id", "name":"$name"},
        "favourites": "$favourites"
    }
}
},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "favourites": { "$push": "$_id.favourites" },
    "length": { "$sum": 1 }
}},
{ "$match": { "length":  2  }}
])
```

Result:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("574cf11b0b3052089fe57605"),
        "favourites" : [ 
            "red", 
            "orange"
        ],
        "length" : 2
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://ilearnasigoalong.blogspot.com/2013/10/efficient-techniques-for-fuzzy-and.html) blog has a simple suggestion of simply just create a query that combines matches of every document by listing the desired attributes one-by-one and assigning each of them a similarity value and simply adding that up as part of the query.  (Example here is cut-past from the blog, but im sure you will be able to fix it for your own data strcture);

```
"$project" : {
  "c" : {"$add" : [
     {"$cond" : [{"$eq" : ["$firstname","John"]},1,0]},
     {"$cond" : [{"$eq" : ["$middleone","Andrew"]},1,0]},
     {"$cond" : [{"$eq" : ["$middletwo","Cartwright"]},1,0]},
     {"$cond" : [{"$eq" : ["$lastname","Smith"]},1,0]}
        ]
  }
```

You can extend this for the Favorites-array by simply taking the search-originators list and include that in the query one element at a time.

The benefit here would be that you can order the result based on what is most similar.