# MongoDB Array Query to return documents that matches Most elements in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

There is a requirement to query the mongodb in a way that it returns the documents in sorted order with most elements matched in Array first.
Example :

```
Doc1 : {_id:1,fruits:['apple','orange','banana']}

Doc2 :{_id:1,fruits:['grapes','apple','strawberry']}
```

If I search for fruits:['apple','orange'] in the collections then Doc1 should be returned. 
Please help in forming the query for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use scoring technique to match the most appropriate array. In terms of Mongo, make use of full text search. The solution is available in the following link (duplicate/similar requirement) [MongoDB compare arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464969/mongodb-compare-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

According to description mentioned in above question please try executing following query in MongoDB shell.

```
db.collection.find{fruits:{$all:['apple','orange']}}
```

In above query $all operator fetch the document where an array field value matches  all values contained in specified array filter

Comment: The question is to match by a close proximity and not exact match for all elements. For example the second array also qualifies but it scores less than the first one.